# publish saved trajectory one by one

Tags: ros, follow-joint-trajectory, joint-trajectory-controller

i have a trajectory from moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan

i am trying to publish all points one by one

```
while ( ros::ok())
{
    ros::spinOnce();

    sendTraj.joint_names = trajFromPlan.joint_names;
    sendTraj.points.resize( 1 );
    sendTraj.points[0].positions = trajFromPlan.points[step].positions;
    sendTraj.points[0].velocities = trajFromPlan.points[step].velocities;
    sendTraj.points[0].accelerations = trajFromPlan.points[step].accelerations;

    //calculating time_from_start and loop perriod
    nextTime = trajFromPlan.points[step + 1].time_from_start - trajFromPlan.points[step].time_from_start
    sendTraj.points[0].time_from_start = nexTime;

    trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory.publish( sendTraj );
    
    ros::Rate rate(nextTime);
    rate.sleep();
}
```

but the rqt grap like that;
[image]
what i expect;
[image]
how can i solve this problem

Comment: what is the actual problem? ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I "publish" the entire previously created trajectory at once, the graph appears smooth and beautiful, but when I send the points within the trajectory one by one, the graph appears rough, as can be seen in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `ros::Rate rate(nextTime)` should be a duration instead: `ros::Duration(nextTime).sleep()`

I am assuming that `time_from_start` is measured in seconds. A `ros::Rate` expects a frequency in Hertz units 'Hz' (1/nextTime) as an input. Since you are calculating nextTime as the subtraction of 2 values measured in seconds, the units of `nextTime` are seconds not Hertz.

Comment: thank you i changed this line but result same